# SSRS/SQL - Can I show the max value of one column based on the grouping of another column within a parent group?

Tags: sql, visual-studio, reporting-services

I have a report that is grouped by the week within SSRS and shows when a job's status has been updated.

```
Week    | Job | Status | Update Date
-------------------------------------
   41   | J40 | 8      | 10/04/2021
        | J40 | 9      | 10/05/2021
        | J23 | 5      | 10/05/2021
-------------------------------------
   40   | J56 | 7      | 09/28/2021
        | J11 | 9      | 10/02/2021
```

So, when the status updates, the job will show up on this report. The date is the date the status was updated. What I would like to accomplish is to only show the latest update for each job per week. In this example, for J40 only the 10/05/2021 row should show like this:

```
Week    | Job | Status | Update Date
-------------------------------------
   41   | J40 | 9      | 10/05/2021
        | J23 | 5      | 10/05/2021
-------------------------------------
   40   | J56 | 7      | 09/28/2021
        | J11 | 9      | 10/02/2021
```

Would it be easier to create a Child group for the Job column and filter that way?

Comment: I personally would always do this work in the dataset query. If you want help on that then edit this question or ask another

Answer (score 0):

Given the status updates aren't necessarily incrementing:

```
SELECT S.Week, S.Job, S.Status, S.UpdateDate
FROM JobStatus AS S
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Job, MAX(UpdateDate) AS MaxDate
    FROM JobStatus
    GROUP BY Job) AS M ON M.Job = S.Job AND M.MaxDate = S.UpdateDate
ORDER BY Week, Job
```

Comment: I think that would only work if the status was only ever incremented, which is not clear from the question

Comment: In a perfect world it would only increment, but unfortunately that is not the case here.

Comment: Okay, I've changed this answer to doing it in the dataset